# Installing libusb-1.0 on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, libusb

It seems that the easiest way to install libusb-1.0.9 onto Windows 7 for use in [Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C++#32-bit_versions) is to use [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) or similar software to build and install it to my computer. Is there an easier way to do it that I have not found, or am I going about this all wrong?

I would like to use libusb to communicate with an [Arduino Due](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardDue), and development will be done in Visual Studio (and maybe [Dev-C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Dev-C%2b%2b)).

Comment: I do recommend you to cross compile this library from Linux, it will be really easy, I promise

Answer (score 3):

You can use [libusb-win32](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki) for this.

To install libusb on Windows 7 [download the bin package for libusb-win32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/files/libusb-win32-releases/1.2.6.0/libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0.zip/download) (this link points to version 1.2.6). Then go to the bin directory and run `inf-wizard.exe`. Here is where you can customize and generate an INF installation file for your device, as well as the installer executables. Select the same bin directory you are running from to place the output of the tool (so that the INF file is next to the `x86`, `amd64` and `ia64` directories).

Now you can run the installation executable. You can also go to Device Manager and right click your device and choose "Update Driver Software" and point directly at your generated INF file.

At this point your device should be loaded, so you should be able to communicate with it by including the `lusb0_usb.h` file in your project (located in the `include` directory) and linking your project to the appropriate LIB file in the `lib` directory. The API can be [found here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki/libusbwin32_documentation#III.Functions).

Comment: I have also tried libusb-win32, and I am equally confused by how to set it up. Maybe I am not google-ing hard enough?

Comment: I tried to summarize the installation steps quickly, hopefully this helps.

Comment: @Preston what I don't get is why do we have to choose USB device? I thought that the point is to install this package so then we can access **any** usb device!

Comment: The way that Windows works you need to know the VID/PID for your device to assoicate it with the kernel driver (through the INF install). You can do this for multiple devices, so assuming you know a few you need they can all be in the same driver. WinUSB works the same way.

Comment: libusb-win32 is a port of libusb-0.1 not libusb-1.0