# Working with USB in Go

Tags: go, usb

Can somebody provide an example of using [`go-libusb`](https://github.com/popons/go-libusb/) (or may be any other lib working with USB in Golang)  .

1. I have created package `libusb`
2. Copied the content from https://github.com/popons/go-libusb/blob/main/libusb.go

There is an error:

```
Unresolved symbol: '_Cstruct_usb_device_descriptor'
```

Thank you.

Comment: you need some kind of c library to compile it with. libusb maybe ? what os are you on ?

Comment: I use Win8. Please correct me if am wrong: I have to download from http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/.  But how to link Go and that library ?

Answer (score 3):

First you have to install libusb from http://www.libusb.org/wiki/libusb-win32, then either change `// #include<usb.h>` to:

```
/*
    #cgo LDFLAGS: -lusb
    #include <usb.h>
*/
```

And `descriptor _Cstruct_usb_device_descriptor` to `descriptor C.struct_usb_device_descriptor`.

Or pull my fork from https://github.com/OneOfOne/go-libusb, I already sent a pull request with the changes.

Comment: "That library is extremely outdated" I will be thankful if you provide me better  option (As for now I wasn't able to find smth. useful)

Comment: BTW, I have also tried to use (test) this package: https://github.com/tarm/goserial.  1) For installation this package I performed "go get https://github.com/tarm/goserial" command 2) New package was created, but  3) it also is not compiled, there are several Errors in serial_windows.go file like : Expression type mismatch, the expected type is uint32. Unfortunately, there are no additional configuration information for that lib, can smb. recommend how to configure or install these libs

Comment: I don't use windows at all.

Comment: Thank you a lot, now it compiles, but during start main there is "exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%".  According to the documentation : "To build cgo packages, just use go build or go install as usual. The go tool recognizes the special "C" import and automatically uses cgo for those files." So, what additional configuration should be added

Comment: that means gcc isn't installed, I really don't know enough about it.

Comment: @ivetkin, you need a GCC-compatible C compiler (and all the accompanying stuff) installed in order to use `cgo` (what @OneOfOne proposed to use).  One way to have one is to install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org).

Comment: @ivetkin, as to `goserial`, it *might* turn out that the package is a bit outdated with regard to current Go, so you might want to run `go vet` on the package's sources and see if it compiles.  To do that, `cd` into the package's directory, `git checkout -b testbranch` and start playing.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I have perforformed the next steps: 1) Installed  http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/. Added bin folder to %Path% 2) Run go-file 3) Receive exception: 37: error: 'usb_control_msg' undeclared (first use in this function)
37: error: 'usb_find_devices' undeclared (first use in this function)
37: error: 'usb_get_string_simple' undeclared (first use in this function)
37: error: 'usb_strerror' undeclared (first use in this function)
37: error: 'usb_bulk_read' undeclared (first use in this function)
...

Answer (score 3):

The [go-libusb package](https://github.com/popons/go-libusb) by [popons](https://github.com/popons) is a wrapper for the [libusb-0.1](http://www.libusb.org) C-based USB driver. [libusb-0.1](http://www.libusb.org) is "deprecated and unmaintained." [Source: [libusb API version overview](http://www.libusb.org/wiki/APIs)]

For using USB with Go, I'd recommend using a [libusb 1.0](http://libusb.info) ([source on GitHub](https://github.com/libusb/libusb)) Go-driver, such as:

- [gousb](https://github.com/kylelemons/gousb/) — Originally created by Kyle Lemons. There are newer forks, such as the one by [truveris](https://github.com/truveris/gousb).
- [libusb](https://github.com/gotmc/libusb) — *Discloure*: I'm the original creator.

Both of the above Go drivers require having the C-version of [libusb](http://libusb.info) installed. To install on Windows, take a look at the [libusb Windows driver installation instructions](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/wiki/Windows#Driver_Installation), which recommend using [Zadig](http://zadig.akeo.ie). You could also look at the SO question [Installing libusb-1.0 on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20315797/95592), but the only answer appears to show how to install libusb-0.1 not libusb-1.0.

As a Windows user, I know this doesn't help you, but for OS X users, libusb can be installed using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
$ brew install libusb
```